# AChartEngine graph using two y axis

Tags: axis, achartengine

I am currently trying to create a graph using AChartEngine containing two y-axis (one to the left, one to the right). Yet, I cannot seem to figure out how I can actually add the second y-Axis. An `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` only has got one `setYTitle()` method.

Has someone ever achieved this and can give me a hint?

Thanks,
Matthias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that, indeed. Please see an example for this [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/MultipleTemperatureChart.java).

The result looks like

[image: this].

Comment: The link is broken, can you provide a new link please?