# Android - inAnimation works for ViewFlipper but outAnimation doesn't

Tags: android, android-animation, viewflipper

I've been trying to implement ViewFlipper and its translate animation. There are many pages I can refer to, but no matter how much I tried, I can't see outAnimation ever happen. Below is my project, and currently no translate animation is seen but IF I COMMENT OUT the vf.setOutAnimation... part, inAnimation animation suddenly starts to work. ...why?

```
package com.example.testview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class TestViewActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private ViewFlipper vf;
    private float firstTouchX;
    private float leaveTouchX;

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    vf.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    firstTouchX = event.getX();
                    break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    leaveTouchX = event.getX();

                if (this.firstTouchX - 50f > leaveTouchX) {

                    vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.right_in));
                    vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_out));
                    vf.showNext();
                }
                if (this.firstTouchX + 50f < leaveTouchX) {

                    vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_in));
                    vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.right_out));
                    vf.showPrevious();
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

res/anim/left_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="350" 
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p" 
    android:toXDelta="0%p"  
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p">
</translate>
```

res/anim/left_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="350"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p">
</translate>
```

res/anim/right_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="350"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p">
</translate>
```

res/anim/right_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="350"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p">
</translate>
```

res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ViewFlipper
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <include
            android:id="@+id/first"
            layout="@layout/first" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/second"
            layout="@layout/second" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/third"
            layout="@layout/third" />

    </ViewFlipper>
```

first.xml / second.xml / third.xml (only their own picture id is different)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/img">
</ImageView>
```

**BIG EDIT**: I just build a smaller project based on my post and it seems to work... perhaps through the process of omitting some codes that I thought unnecessary to start a discussion caused my problem.... I'm really sorry if anybody made an attempt to answer. I'll do a more survey and hope I can post breakdowns that can be of use for later references, unless mods delete this question.

**BIG EDIT2**: Today I tried once again, and it DIDN'T WORK, presumably because I used Android ARM 2.2 Emulator. Once I switch into ARM/Inter 2.3.3, it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786435/achartengine-graph-using-two-y-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, replace outAnimation into inAnimation like,

```
            if (this.firstTouchX - 50f > leaveTouchX) {

                vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_out));
                vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.right_in));
                vf.showNext();
            }
            if (this.firstTouchX + 50f < leaveTouchX) {

                vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.right_out));
                vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_in));
                vf.showPrevious();
            }
            break;
```

And then try It might be work!

Comment: Hey, thanks lots. I have to sort out my problem and then figure out what's the exact cause, so please wait a bit until I take yours as an accepted answer.

Comment: Hey, really sorry to say that it appears it's my emulator's fault. My PC wasn't that strong, so it couldn't display animation... (although the same thing occasionally happens on Macbook Air 2012 model (Core i7)). Anyway, thanks!